# python write a specific column from many files to one file

Tags: python, file, awk

I am trying to read many files and from these files to write on specific column to another file. I read how it can be done but it is not working. Could someone help me implementing pawk in my script?

```
    j = j + 1   
    #with open('a1_gather_{j}.txt'.format(j=j)) as f2:  
    f2 = open('a1_gather_{j}.txt'.format(j=j), 'w')
        k=k+1
        print k 
        f1 = open('a1_{k}'.format(k=k))
        # with open('a1_{k}'.format(k=k), 'a') as f1:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            print i
            if line.startswith(searchquery):
                f2.write(line)
                f2.write(lines[i + 1])
                f2.write(lines[i + 2])
                i = i+1
            else :
                i = i+1
        #os.close(f1)
        f1.close()

# awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]?a[FNR]" "$2:$2}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]}' *

f2.close()
```

I preferred the `f = open` instead of `with open` to avoid the error `IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')`.

The files to read have 1000 lines and two columns. I need only the second column of each file to be written to another file.

Could someone correct my script and indicate how can pawk be used?

Comment: Do you need pawk to do this, or just to do this? It would be much simpler if you would use awk!

Comment: Just to do this. I searched for awk and I find only posts for pawk due to python

Comment: do you need the columns pasted side by side or appended?

Comment: @ karafka, either ways are ok. My script read the columns but does not wirte them at the write file. And I cannot understand the functionality of awk

Answer (score 1):

For this particular task, you could abandon python completely, and use the [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) command instead:

```
cut -f2 a1_{1..10}.txt > a1_gather.txt
```

By default, it uses tabs as column separator, `-d` option lets you change that.

`{start..stop}` notation gives you finer control over the files that get matched.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to write second column from `a1_*` files to `a1_gather` file and use **awk** as you mentioned in comment you could run simple command in terminal:

```
cat a1_* | awk '{print $2}' > a1_gather
```

Where:

- `cat a1_*` stands for *from every file that filename starts with `a1_`*
- `awk '{print $2}'` means *print second column*
- `> a1_gather` is *and save it to file `a1_gather`*

In case you would be more interested using awk in the future, [this is really useful tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to learn from.

Comment: Is only this command line enough? Or do I have to run the whole loop? Is the awk part of the loop?

Comment: well I am not an informatic professional but this is not working. I have to figure out the syntax and the place in my script. Thank you at any case!

Answer (score 0):

```
f2 = open('a1_gather_{j}.txt'.format(j=j), 'w')
   f1 = open('a1_{k}.txt'.format(k=k))
   lines = f1.readlines()
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):       
       print(repr(line))                
       f2.write(line)
       i = i+1
   f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This one reads and writes the whole lines. I can work with this also, but any suggestion for the knowledge how can one read and write only the second column is appreciated and wellcome.